# Implemeting a File Character Analysis

Tags: java

I'm stuck on my assignment and wanted some pointers on an algorithm.
I am presented with text files that represent different images. blank space is where no pixels are on and '&' represents an on pixel.

The aim is i am given a 100 x 100 image text file to analyse and work out the probability that the object is there and then the co-ordinate of where it is on the file.

I know that i have to use character analysis of some sort but i feel that i have to check for example 10x10 grids at a time, analyse how many pixels are on and work out the certainty that the object is there. (This is because more or less pixels can be on and the object still present)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: a smaller image comprised of & characters for on pixels

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question correctly. One thing that will change the answer is whether or not you know the object beforehand. If you are looking for an arbitrary pattern, it is somewhat more difficult, but still feasible. To find an object that you know what it will look like will come down to nested for loops and a solid understanding of 2D arrays. You can pull in each line of the text file and look for an '&'. If it finds one, it begins looking for the rest of the pattern based on the location relative to that first '&'.

For example, if you are looking for a diagonal line from top left to bottom right, you would continue along until you came to the first '&'. After that, you would look at the cell one column over and 1 row down. If that is an ampersand as well, you know that you have a diagonal line. If not, just keep going along after the first '&'.

```
for (int c = 0; c < textArray.length; c++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < textArray[c].length; i++)
    {
        Look at the character
        If it is '&'
            Look for the next character and so forth
            If the pattern is there
               return true
    }
}
```

See if that helps get your algorithm rolling. You will need to make sure to check for legal bounds in your arrays in order to combat out of bounds exceptions.

Comment: Ok so i now have the contents of the file stored into a 2D array. The problem i have now is I'm trying to work out how i can check a 10x10 square in the 100x100 array. The issue is how to keep up with each block. Thanks

Comment: Ok so the pseudo code would be:
Read a file containing 10000 chars some blank spaces some & (100x100)
Use loops to search whether an object of a certain pattern exists
If its more than a certain percentage likely then print its co-ordinate
I really cannot understand how to go forward with this problem, my loop is like this:
`code`
for (int i = 0; i < fileToChar.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < fileToChar[0].length; j++) {
                if(fileToChar[i][j] == '&'){
                    CHECKS GO HERE!!!
                }
            }
        }

Any help would be apprecaited...

Comment: I don't think you have to even worry about the percentage likely. For this application, it either is the pattern or it isn't. Basically, if you find an '&', you then look where the next '&' in the pattern is supposed to be. If it's there too, then look for the third '&'. If it's not, then you know it's not the pattern, so you can continue looking like normal. You also might want to edit your question and include the code or pseudocode that you have gotten. It's much easier to see it when it's not crammed into a comment. You're doing well, just keep going!